# Download Mathematica resource from another source

Tags: machine-learning, resourceobject

I want to do machine learning on Mathematica, however when I use `obj = ResourceObject["CIFAR-10"];` to load the dataset, it shows errors after the downloading process, which says `Wolfram\Objects\Resources\f95\f9519a0f-2f42-4ef8-ba73-b05c928596ae\d\ ownload\TrainingData\315219b38a46ec88\data\data.WXF is corrupt and \ does not contain a properly serialized expression`. This persists even after I deleted that file. So how can I get the correct file for usage, from another download source, perhaps?

Comment: Version 13.0 If I say: `obj = ResourceObject["CIFAR-10"];` and then `obj` I properly get `ResourceObject[...]` .

Comment: @DanielHuber this did not work for me, even though 309MB of data have been downloaded

Comment: Try with a new kernel. And I have version 13.0  and Windows 10

Comment: @DanielHuber I use version 12.3 and Windows 10. Restarting the kernel/ deleting the file/ reinstalling doesn't work

Comment: Maybe it is a problem that has been fixed in version 13.0.

Comment: The data retrieval works fine in v12.0 on Win10-64. I think this might have been a temporary glitch.

Comment: I just tried it in 13.0 on Mac, and it was fine. Maybe give it another go? Also, with common open datasets like CIFAR-*, it's usually easy to find downloads of them on the web - you'd have to write your own ingestion code, of course, but that shouldn't be too bad.